# Pass variable to filename in Windows FOR / DO Batch File

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, 7-zip

I have the following code where I systematically go through and compress each file individually. I don't care what the file name is, but I want it hidden more or less so will just call each file "file 1", "file 2", "file 3" etc.

But how do I pass the variable `fn=file!count!` to the 7z.exe command line? I added the `echo` commands just to make sure the variable was working, and it does. But how do I get fn to resolve as actual "file1" "file2", etc in the 7z command line? I've tried %, !, %!, !%, %%... lol. It just gives a blank file name or !fn! or %fn% not the actual variable value.

Code is here and thanks in advance for any assistance:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d E:\Temp\ziptest\Documents
set /A count=0
for /r %%a in (*) do (
cd "%%~pa" 
set /A count += 1
echo !count!
set fn=file!count!
echo !fn!
pause
REM 7z.exe a -mx9 -mmt12 -sdel -pt3st! -mhe=on "!fn!.7z" "%%~nxa"
)
endlocal
```

Example of output where you can see it's incrementing properly and resolving file## properly as well:

```
E:\Temp\ziptest>setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

E:\Temp\ziptest>cd /d E:\Temp\ziptest\Documents

E:\Temp\ziptest\Documents>set /A count=0

E:\Temp\ziptest\Documents>for /R %a in (*) do (
cd "%~pa"
 set /A count += 1
 echo !count!
 set fn=file!count!
 echo !fn!
 pause
 REM 7z.exe a -mx9 -mmt12 -sdel -pt3st! -mhe=on "!fn!.7z" "%~nxa"
)

E:\Temp\ziptest\Documents>(
cd "\Temp\ziptest\Documents\"
 set /A count += 1
 echo !count!
 set fn=file!count!
 echo !fn!
 pause
 REM 7z.exe a -mx9 -mmt12 -sdel -pt3st! -mhe=on "!fn!.7z" "Book1.xlsx"
)
1
file1
Press any key to continue . . .

E:\Temp\ziptest\Documents>(
cd "\Temp\ziptest\Documents\"
 set /A count += 1
 echo !count!
 set fn=file!count!
 echo !fn!
 pause
 REM 7z.exe a -mx9 -mmt12 -sdel -pt3st! -mhe=on "!fn!.7z" "COVID-19 Oakland County.xlsx"
)
2
file2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What happens if you replace REM with echo?

Comment: Thanks, but same result with Echo. Not sure why it's not passing variable.

Comment: Try removing the quotes.

Comment: Thanks. But I've tried every combination of !! %% %! !% double quotes single quotes, it just doesn't seem to want to resolve that within the Do loop. I think it has something to do with the do loop.

Comment: So, what this **`-pt3st!`** suppose to do? This **`!`** in **`-pt3st`**

Comment: Thanks @ItWasn'tMe ... yeah I just found this out myself. the -p sets password for the file, test password was "t3st!". I removed the "!" and all is well.

Comment: Try ^!! == !  by using ^!! result !  so, using **`-pt3st^!!`** results: **`-pt3st!`**

Comment: Thank you! So very helpful! I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fillings that all you need to do is **`call something`**

Obs.: Remove extra space in `set /A count[espace]+=1` and use **`@echo off`** and replace **`%%~pa`** to **`%%~dpa`**

```all-bat
@echo off 

cd/d "E:\Temp\ziptest\Documents"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%a in (*) do (
   set /A "count+=1+0"
   cd /d "%%~dpa"
   set "fn=file!count!"
   echo\!fn! 
   echo\!count!
   7z.exe a -mx9 -mmt12 -sdel -pt3st -mhe=on "!fn!.7z" "%%~nxa"
  )

endlocal
```

- Sort compacted option...

```all-bat
@echo off 

cd /d "E:\Temp\ziptest\Documents" && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*)do set /A "count+=1+0" && cd /d "%%~dpa" && call set "fn=file!count!" && (
echo\!fn! & echo\!count! && call 7z.exe a -mx9 -mmt12 -sdel -pt3st! -mhe=on "!fn!.7z" "%%~nxa"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I figured out what it is... smh... It was the exclamation point "!" in my pw "t3st!"...

Syntax, syntax, syntax!

Comment: @HTWingNut Take a look in **`cd /d "%~pa"`** have to be **`cd /d "%~dpa"`**