# Windows Batch Script and handling file names with "!" Exclamation point in For Loop

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, environment-variables

Part of my script I am having issue with is here:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*) do (
cd "%%~dpa" 
set /A count += 1
set fn=file!count!
%batchdir%\7z.exe a -mx9 -sdel -p"%password%" -mhe=on "!fn!.7z" "%%~nxa"
)
```

But the filename variable <strike>`fn`</strike> `%%~nxa` can't properly process file names with an exclamation point `!` in them.

Is there a way to work around this?

Thanks.

EDIT: Change `fn` to `%%~nxa` that is the issue

Comment: No. It's a single for loop.

Comment: Here is full code if you want to see it: https://pastebin.com/A9efaGmy

Comment: 1- Why not try this for loop code without **[`echo\ `](https://superuser.com/a/1542282/969781)** 2 - remove spaces and add "double quotes" in **`set /a "count+=1+0" `** and **`set "fn=file!count!"`**

Comment: Thank you for your time. But ugh. I realized it's not the `!fn!` that's the issue. it 's the "%%~nxa" which is the file name and if the file name includes an `!` it drops the `!` So is there a way to escape that ! somehow? I guess that's what I get for trying to debug when dead tired.

Comment: For every programmer, going without sleep or resting is just `True` or `False`, possibly every `day()`.

Comment: Haha. Yeah. This is more a personal project. But I'll hit it up tomorrow after a few cold ones and some rest! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, enabled delayed expansion chokes down unescaped exclamation marks. For proof, see the following simple script and its output below:

```
@ECHO OFF
pushd d:\bat\Unusual Names\exclamations
echo(
echo dir /B:
dir /B

echo(
echo loop with EnableDelayedExpansion:
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%a in (*) do (
  echo %%~nxa
)
ENDLOCAL

echo(
echo loop with DisableDelayedExpansion:
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /r %%a in (*) do (
  echo %%~nxa
)
ENDLOCAL
popd
```

**Output**: `D:\bat\SU\1552202.bat`

> ```
> dir /B:
> 01exclam!ation.txt
> 02exc!lam!ation.txt
> 04exc!lam!ation!OS!%OS%.txt
>
> loop with EnableDelayedExpansion:
> 01exclamation.txt
> 02excation.txt
> 04excationWindows_NT%OS%.txt
>
> loop with DisableDelayedExpansion:
> 01exclam!ation.txt
> 02exc!lam!ation.txt
> 04exc!lam!ation!OS!%OS%.txt
> ```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38027430/3439404) (there are shown two ways of processing such data with an exclamation mark). Your script could work if improved e.g. as follows:

```
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem                       ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ ← ← ← important!
set /A count=0
for /r %%a in (*) do (
  pushd "%%~dpa"
  set "file_nxa=%%~nxa"
  call :do7z 
  popd
)
goto :eof

:do7z
set /A count += 1
set fn=file%count%
%batchdir%\7z.exe a -mx9 -sdel -p"%password%" -mhe=on "%fn%.7z" "%file_nxa%"
goto :eof
```